# How does one separate a Numbers spreadsheet with multiple (4) tabs into separate files?

Tags: macos, numbers, file

I have been given a spreadsheet with 4 separate tabs/sheets. I would like to separate them into different files. I know that I can cut-and-paste and create new files but is there a simpler/easier way to do that?

Comment: AppleScript can do it, but for 4 tabs, unless this was a frequently run process, it wouldn't be simpler or easier than copy/pasting 8 times. See something like: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2613193 Would obviously need adjusting to your specific requirements.

Comment: If this was a once-off situation, I'd just save the file four times and then edit each one to remove the three sheets you don't want.